# Clojure{Script} protocol naming

Tags: clojure, protocols, naming, clojurescript

What is the idiomatic way to name a Clojure protocol ?
`IProtocol` or `Protocol`, or do they present different use cases, and why ?

So far I use `IProtocol` when dealing with interoperability (Java or js/google-closure in ClojureScript).

I am also wondering about the naming convention of the method names :
`-my-method` vs `my-method`. I have seen both in the wild (in ClojureScript codebase), and could not come up with a rationale to explain when use one or the other.

So, what is the idiomatic way to name abstractions in Clojure and ClojureScript ?

Comment: Difference between -my-method and my-method is  that "-" is default prefix for gen-class. You can specify another prefix in gen-class construction.

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious thanks for the pointer I wasn't aware of that. Could you expand a bit ? This means it is useful in interop scenarios ?

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious otherwise that would be an answer that I could accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a way of how you allow `java` to call `clojure` code.

If you create, for example, `lein new app testapp` (`lein` is command line interface for `leiningen` a widely used clojure projects automation tool) you may see in your core.clj a line

```
(ns testapp.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main 
  "Comment line"
  [&args]
  (println "Hello, World!"))
```

Here `ns` is a macro that makes easier to define namespaces and other things.
Important thing here is `(:gen-class)`. Let unwrap the macro:

```
> (macroexpand-1 '(ns testapp.core (:gen-class)))
(do 
  .... 
  (clojure.core/gen-class :name "testapp.core" :impl-ns testapp.core :main true)
  ....)
```

This code will tell the compiler to generate the byte code for the class named "testapp.core" and this class marked as ":main true". This mark will create a declaration of static public `main` function in the class, so `jvm` could start a program calling the `main` function. By java language convention the program entry point should be called `main`. You can add different methods to `gen-class` (see docs) declaring types or arguments and return value, but, as I can assume, it can be useful to separate `java` statically typed methods from your `clojure` functions to prevent name collapse. So `gen-class` allows you to define a `:prefix` that you use to name your java class implementation. Default one is "-". So you create a function `-main` and in `java` code it would look like `testapp.core.main`.

We can change it

```
(ns testapp.core
  (:gen-class :prefix my-prefix-))
```

When you compile your code to jar and run with `java -jar` you get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
testapp.core/my-prefix-main not defined
```

Ok, we forgot to rename our implementation:

```
(defn my-prefix-main [&args] (println "Hello, World!"))
```

Compile and run:

```
"Hello, World!"
```

P. S. I can't tell you about naming conventions of protocols and interfaces that are used in `clojure`.

Comment: What does `gen-class` have to do with protocols?

Comment: the question is more about naming variables, then about a protocols. There is a second part of tge question about -func-name, I answered in a comment and author asked me to explain a little bit more.